# Is it possible to put centered lines in a multicolumn?

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I want to do something like this:

[image: Error entries with centered lines]

Unfortunately, I have not found a solution yet. Can someone help?

Here is a piece of my table:

```
\begin{table}[H]  
\centering    

\begin{tabular}{lccccccc}                                                                                                                       
\toprule
Parameter & $\epsilon_{1}$ & $\epsilon_{2}$ & $\epsilon_{3}$ & 
$\epsilon_{4}$ & $\epsilon_{5}$ & $\epsilon_{6}$ & $\epsilon_{7}$ \\ 
\midrule
$1.$ & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Error} \\
$2.$ & $3.3714 $& $-2.5266 $& $0.0000 $& $-0.0000 $& $-0.0000 $& $0.0000 
$& $6.3746 $\\                                                             
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}  

\caption{Sensitivity analysis                                                                                     
\label{table:SensAnalysis}                                                                                                                
\end{table}
```

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try with some raised `\hrulefill`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a macro `\dashfill` that repeats overlapping dashes to fill some space.

I also add some suggestions for the table, using `siunitx`.

The `\Error` macro receives as argument the number of columns to span.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\newcommand{\Error}[1]{%
  \multicolumn{#1}{c}{\dashfill\quad Error\quad\dashfill}%
}
\newcommand{\dashfill}{%
  --\kern-0.2em\leaders\hbox to .25em{\hss--\hss}\hfill\kern-0.2em--%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-2pt} % to make the table fit

\begin{tabular}{
 l
 S[table-format=1.4]
 S[table-format=-1.4]
 S[table-format=1.4]
 S[table-format=-1.4]
 S[table-format=-1.4]
 S[table-format=1.4]
 S[table-format=1.4]
}
\toprule
Parameter & {$\epsilon_{1}$} & {$\epsilon_{2}$} & {$\epsilon_{3}$} &
{$\epsilon_{4}$} & {$\epsilon_{5}$} & {$\epsilon_{6}$} & {$\epsilon_{7}$} \\
\midrule
1. & \Error{7} \\
2. & 3.3714 & -2.5266 & 0.0000 & -0.0000 & -0.0000 & 0.0000& 6.3746 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Sensitivity analysis}                                           
\label{table:SensAnalysis}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Avoid the `[H]` option.

[image]

Comment: Thank your very much. Serves the purpose while it leaves the cleanest code and looks best (for my taste).

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,booktabs,array}
\newcommand\longemdash{\textemdash\textemdash%
    \textemdash\textemdash\textemdash\textemdash%
    \textemdash\textemdash\textemdash\textemdash}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]  
\centering    
$\begin{array}{@{} >{$}l<{$} *{7}{c} @{}}                                                                                                                       
\toprule
Parameter & \epsilon_{1} & \epsilon_{2} & \epsilon_{3} 
          & \epsilon_{4} & \epsilon_{5} & \epsilon_{6} 
          & \epsilon_{7} \\ 
\midrule
1. & \multicolumn{7}{>{$}c<{$}}{\longemdash\qquad Error\qquad\longemdash} \\
2. & 3.3714 & -2.5266 & 0.0000 & -0.0000 & -0.0000 & 0.0000 & 6.3746 \\                                                             
\bottomrule
\end{array}$
\caption{Sensitivity analysis} \label{table:SensAnalysis}                                                                                                                
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this, with `booktabs`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{l!{\vrule width \heavyrulewidth}*{7}{>{$}c<{$}}}
& \\[-1.5ex]
\toprule
Parameter & \epsilon_{1} & \epsilon_{2} & \epsilon_{3} & \epsilon_{4} & \epsilon_{5} & \epsilon_{6} & \epsilon_{7} \\
1. & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Error} \\[-1.5ex]
\cmidrule(lr{-0.8em}){2-4}\cmidrule(l{-0.8em}r){6-8}
\addlinespace[\dimexpr1.5ex-\cmidrulewidth]
2. & 3.3714 & -2.5266 & 0.0000 & -0.0000 & -0.0000 & 0.0000 & 6.3746 \\
3. & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Error} \\[-1.5ex]
\cmidrule(lr{-0.8em}){2-4}\cmidrule(l{-0.8em}r){6-8}
\addlinespace[\dimexpr1.5ex-\cmidrulewidth]
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sensitivity analysis}
\label{table:SensAnalysis}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]